# Displaying the custom taxonomies side by side on the admin dashboard

Tags: custom-taxonomy, admin, user-interface

I got 5 top level cats and for each of these top level cats, I have directly corresponding 5 non-hierarchal custom taxonomies.

By default, WordpPress UI display these CT's one after the other. Right below the cats... By using a plug in, I can define the order... As far as admin UI options, WP gives me the ability to change the UI from 1 col to 2 col view which helps but not totally.

In 2 col view, I can easily see that I  got plenty of room to fit in at least 3 or 4 CT's floating next to each other. When I turned the 2-col view however,   current UI allows me to drag only one tag box into what's below the post content editor. So, with 2 col view, I don't get to do what I wanted to. There simply is no point to drag a tag box below the post editor cause it is unnecessarily too long.

Is it possible to make the tag boxes to float right next to one another? 
So, The more room there is, the more the CT's show side by side.

```
post content___________________________________________________cats box here

CT 1__________CT 2__________CT 3__________CT 4__________        


CT 5__________
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using CSS to affect the display when they are in the main column? That seems like the best solution to me. The main problem is that the actual layout of the box changes when you move them into the main column to use the horizontal space better (tabs at left instead of above list). You'll have to reverse-engineer all the CSS that changes the layout to make it behave like it does in the sidebar.

Either way it will probably be a pretty complicated chunk of CSS, and will need to be reviewed in the future when the styles that define the default behavior are changed.